# What is the purpose of rb_entry() macro in rbtree.h

Tags: process, linux-kernel, containers, scheduling, red-black-tree

I want to know the contribution of [#define rb_entry(ptr,type,member) container_of(ptr,type,member) macro Line 50 of rbtree.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rbtree.h#L50) in process scheduling. The macro has been used in [__enqueue_entity()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L507) defined in fair.c

Where are the process and their vruntime stored.Need detail explanation.

I am unable to figure out how to add a linked list corresponding to each node of the red black tree of Linux Kernel and to perform the insertion and deletion from the new red black tree.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciable.

Comment: The macro container_of() is commonly used in the Linux kernel to find an address of a member of a struct by subtracting from a pointer.  In this case it is going to get a sched_entity from an rb_node.  See this: http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html  I'm unclear on the other questions.

Comment: Thank you @peter. The link explained the macro container_of beautifully. The other question is: during process scheduling does the process structure (task_struct) and the vruntime are stored in the red black tree. In either case how are they stored? and if i want to add a linked list corresponding to each node of the red black tree, then what are the steps to be carried out.

Comment: I think you would have to create another rb tree at init time and insert/manipulate it in the same way that the scheduler is doing it.  You could modify the kernel to do that in the same place.  Navigate the source to see where and how the rb tree is created and maybe create another separate tree there.

Comment: currently the function is rb_entry(parent, struct sched_entity, run_node) where both parent and run_node are of type rb_node. But my implementation includes parent to be of type rb_node and run_node to be of linked_list_node type. While doing so, incompatible type error will occur bcoz of container_of(). So, i want to know the way to avoid the error and meet the target. Also please give me the names of any tool that can help me to visualize the changes made to Kernel source code and debug it like any C or Java program. Thank you @Peter..

Comment: Debugging the kernel is difficult because most platforms do not have any easy way to step through the code.  You can do simple debugging with printk() statements.  Also look into Jprobes and Kprobes.  You can view the kernel source online, by platform and version, at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/ .  Also available is the list of patches that have gone into the kernel over time: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/